# Drawing polygon and fill it

Tags: android, paint, ondraw

what I like to do is to draw a polygon and when it's completed I want to fill the polygon with a translucent color.

I'm able to draw a polygon by using canvas.drawLine(...), but can't fill it.

I know in java-awt it's easy, but I can't find it in Android.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanx.

Comment: Can you use already filled polygon?

Comment: I have the points which define the polygon. I'm able to draw a polygon with these points by drawing a line from p1 to p2, p2 to p3, ... and at last from px back to p1 to close the drawing. Now I would like the drawn polygon to fill with a color.

Comment: why don't you draw a filled polygon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do something like this

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

And draw

```
yourCanvas.drawPath(path,mPaint);
```

For details you can check [PAINT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) and [PATH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)